# Is it possible to create `html5 canvas` dynamically with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is it possible to create HTML5 `canvas` dynamically with the mouse?

For example: I want to use my mouse to draw HTML5 canvas then load content into the different canvas.

3 hour I search over the internet for a demo and I found nothing about that possibility.

Comment: *`"then load content into the different canvas."`* can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a canvas on the mouse location

http://jsfiddle.net/v4nm487b/

```
document.onmousedown=mouseDown;
document.onmouseup=mouseUp;
var x1,y1;

function mouseDown(e){
    x1=e.clientX;
    y1=e.clientY;
}

function mouseUp(e){
    var can = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    can.style.position = "absolute";
    can.style.left = x1+"px";
    can.style.top = y1+"px";
    can.width=Math.abs(x1-e.clientX);
    can.height=Math.abs(y1-e.clientY);
    can.style.border="1px solid black"
    document.body.appendChild(can);
}
```

But what do you mean with load the content?

edit: dynamic content

You can give the canvas an id and use that to draw on it

In this exemple the created canvases have the id canN (can0,can1,canN)

If we presse 0 on the numpad (keycode 48), I fill canvas can(48-48)= can0

This ofcourse only work up to 9 but it does prove it can(vas) be done

http://jsfiddle.net/v4nm487b/6/

Comment: Thank You, load content means, i want to load picture and/or video inside canvas dynamically created

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this for certain, as I've never tried it, but you might look into the [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) and [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) events. You could create an element that the user can drag in and listen for those events on it like this:

```js
var startX, startY, endX, endY;
$('#drag')
  .mousedown(function(e) {
    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY;
    $('#start').text(startX + ", " + startY);
  })
  .mouseup(function(e) {
    endX = e.pageX;
    endY = e.pageY;
    $('#end').text(endX + ", " + endY);
  });
```

```css
#drag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start"></div>
<div id="end"></div>
<div id="drag"></div>
```

That gives you the start and end positions of the drag, you can then append a canvas element with some absolute positioning based on those coordinates. Hope this helps!